# Problem with vertical alignment in minipage, in the presence of colors.

Tags: color, minipage, vertical

I am using two minipages. If I use colors, the top rows do not align. Why is that? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{Without colors, the second column aligns nicely with the top row of the first. 
} 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{
Nice alignment.
}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{With colors, however, the second column does not align with the top row of the first.
} 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{
{\color{green}Problem...}
}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because colors are *whatsits* and adding a color in vertical mode is somehow difficult. Inserting *whatsits* isn't transparent in any case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{Without colors, the second column aligns nicely with the top row of the first.}% 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{\special{}Nice alignment.}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You can add `\leavevmode` before `\color` to change the color in the horizontal mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}


\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{Without colors, the second column aligns nicely with the top row of the first.}% 
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{Nice alignment.}%
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{With colors, however, the second column does not align with the top row of the first.}%
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
{{\leavevmode\color{green}Problem...}}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```